# Angular fails to load one of my modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following angular module in a file:

```
angular.module('swagger', [])
.factory('swaggerApi', function () {
    return new Swagger({
        url: 'http://localhost:8081/api-docs',
        usePromise: true
    });
});
```

Afterward in another file I try to use this module as follows, where 'swagger' is the module name:

```
angular.module('GlobalFactoryMethodes', ['swagger'])
```

in my html file I load the 'swagger' module first and my 'GlobalFactoryMethodes' second. However I get the following error message:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module swagger due to:
```

Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'swagger' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

I am new to angular and thought this is how modules suppose to work, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
angular.module('swagger', []);

angular.module('swagger')
   .factory('swaggerApi', function () {
       return new Swagger({
         url: 'http://localhost:8081/api-docs',
         usePromise: true
       });
   });
```

And now add your new module:

`angular.module('GlobalFactoryMethodes', ['swagger'])`

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to declare all module dependencies in one file, that loaded first:

**index.js:**

```
angular.module('swagger', []);
angular.module('GlobalFactoryMethodes', ['swagger']);
```

And then just extend each with providers:

**swagger.js:**

```
angular.module('swagger')
  .factory('swaggerApi', swaggerApi);
```